# Custom rake task for mountable engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am unable to run a custom rake task in a mountable engine I created. When you create the mountable engine, by default, there is a Rails.root/lib/tasks directory with a rake file named after the engine:

```
internal_management_system.rake
```

Inside this file, I create a simple task:

```
task :internal_management_system do
  puts 'hello world'
end
```

Now from Rails.root directory, I try to run it:

```
$ rake internal_management_system
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'internal_management_system'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you give your task a namespace it should work. So in your internal_management_system.rake file put:

```
namespace :db do
 task :internal_management_system do
  puts 'hello world'
 end 
end
```

Then run the command:

```
$ rake db:internal_management_system
```

Comment: This would work fine for a regular app. But this does not work for mountable engine.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to run it from the dummy app root. Apparently you cannot run it from the engine root.

So in engine root, you have

```
/lib/tasks/hello.rake
```

And its contents:

```
task :hello do
  puts 'hello world'
end
```

And then go to the dummy application and run `rake hello`